# How to convert data frame column values from string to a 2d matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert my model training code from using numpy arrays to a pandas data frame. The reason for this is that I was having trouble allocating the entire array to hold all of the training data at once. I have a data frame that I'm reading from a CSV. For convenience sake, let's assume there are three columns:

```
column_one, column_two, column_three
one_one,    two_one,    three_one
one_two,    two_two,    three_two
one_three,  two_three,  three_three
```

All of the values are strings. As input to train my model, I'd like to convert each value into a 2D matrix. The conversion should look something like this:

```
all_data = pandas.read_csv('my.csv')

charset = sorted(list(...)) # List of all unique characters in the data set
max_len = ... # Maximum length of all values

def transform(string):
    data = np.zeros((max_len, len(charset)), dtype=np.float32)
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        data[i, charset[char]] = 1.
    return data

all_data['column_one'] = all_data['column_one'].apply(transform)
all_data['column_two'] = all_data['column_two'].apply(transform)
all_data['column_three'] = all_data['column_three'].apply(transform)
```

The issue is that when I go to input this data into my model.fit call like so:

```
model.fit([all_data['column_one'], all_data['column_two']], all_data['column_three'],
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

I get an error: `Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)`

Any tips on how to properly convert my data into a data frame would be helpful.

Comment: Do you need to have each occurrence within a cell to be counted as unique, and, based on this, to have `1` instead of each? If so, you might take a look at [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) or [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Comment: @alphamu no each value in each CSV cell is a string. I'm trying to convert that string into a matrix where each row represents the character index and each column represents the character class. So if the available character classes were 'a', 'm', and 'x', my name would be `[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is not that you pass a list of two pandas Series containing a 2D-array in each cell? never really used Tensorflow, but maybe try to reshape your input, here an idea but probably not working directly `np.stack([np.stack([transform(row) for row in all_data['column_one']]), np.stack([transform(row) for row in all_data['column_two']]) ])` and `np.stack([transform(row) for row in all_data['column_three']])` for the output. also there is probably something faster to use to perform similar operation

Comment: Also never used Tensorflow, but have rewritten your code above the line with model fit call as follows: ```max_len = max(len(item) for item in all_data.stack().values)
charset = sorted({char for item in all_data.stack().values for char in item})
charmap = {char: _ for _, char in enumerate(charset)}


def transform(cell):
    data = np.zeros((max_len, len(charmap)), dtype=np.float32)
    for _, char in enumerate(list(cell)):
        data[_, charmap[char]] = 1.
    return data


all_data = all_data.applymap(transform)```

Would that work for your task? May post it as an answer

Comment: You need provide a [mre]. Anyway, you are giving inputs of type ```[S, S]``` and ```[S]```, to the ```fit()```, where S is a pandas.Series of elements of type ```numpy.ndarray```. Convert inputs to ```ndarray```s of a higher dimension, using ```np.stack()```, as alphamu said.